# Yet another question on iPhone compatible web page

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I would like to create web page which has to compatible on iPhone..

i want to know how to design the web page for iphone.

Pls provide me the sample html code for a web page . i mean i would like to know how much should be the screen size of the web page etc...

Kindly guide me on this

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE1

can you give me a sample html code ( layout) which can run on iphone browser

Comment: The screen size of a non-retina display iPhone is 320x480, 640x960 for retina. Can't give you anything else since you're barely asking a question.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a 'give me the codez' website. A simple search on Google reveals this: http://snippetspace.com/projects/iwebkit/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample HTML template that will run perfectly on an iPhone:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: I think he wants to make WebApp Style HTML Pages..but awesome answer still! :D